# Deploying a Rails app with mix-and-match Rails engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-engines

We are trying to structure a Rails app that will be made of several Rails engines. Each engine provides a given functionality. The main two requirements are:

1. We need to be able to custom deploy (mix and match rails engines) this rails app to a given client
2. We need to be able to support different version of the rails engines. Basically to support the mix and match across different versions.

I am seeking any advice and recommendations on the truly tried way to go about. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you will have to at least write automation scripts (or something of the same effect) to dynamically change code in the following places during deployment,

- Gemfile
- routes.rb
- config/initializers
- Any Rails Engine specific logic (if wanted devise authentication, need to add controller prefilters)

I think it would be more maintainable to have a prototype repository that you fork and manually tweak for each instance. This would make sense if you don't have a high volume of instance specific applications. For a semi low instance volume, I think automation would hurt more than help.

Or, another option might be including all features and "silence" or "deactivate" unwanted features per instance.